# Eigen: Efficiently storing the output of a matrix evaluation in a raw pointer

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am using some legacy C code that passing around lots of raw pointers. To interface with the code, I have to pass a function of the form:

```
const int N = ...;

T * func(T * x)  {
    // TODO Put N elements in x
    return x + N;
}
```

where this function should write the result into `x`, and then return `x`.

Internally, in this function, I am using Eigen extensively to perform some calculations. Then I write the result back to the raw pointer using the `Map` class. A simple example which mimics what I am doing is this:

```
const int N = 5;
T * func(T * x)  {

    // Do a lot of operations that result in some matrices like
    Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 > A = ... 
    Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 > B = ... 

    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 >> constraint(x);
    constraint = A - B;

    return x + N;
}
```

Obviously, there is much more complicated stuff going on internally, but that is the gist of it... Do some calculations with Eigen, then use the `Map` class to write the result back to the raw pointer.

Now the problem is that when I profile this code with Callgrind, and then view the results with KCachegrind, the lines

`constraint = A - B;`

are almost always the bottleneck. This is sort of understandable, because such lines could/are potentially doing three things:

1. Constructing the Map object
2. Performing the calculation
3. Writing the result to the pointer

So it is understandable that this line might have the longest runtime. But I am a little bit worried that perhaps I am somehow doing an extra copy in that line before the data gets written to the raw pointer.

So is there a better way of writing the result to the raw pointer? Or is that the idiom I should be using?

In the back of my mind, I am wondering if using the `placement new` syntax would buy me anything here.

Note: This code is mission critical and should run in realtime, so I really need to squeeze every ounce of speed out of it. For instance, getting this call from a runtime of 0.12 seconds to 0.1 seconds would be huge for us. But code legibility is also a huge concern since we are constantly tweaking the model used in the internal calculations.

Comment: So it looks in your example that you have created constraint and passed it's constructor an argument; you then perform your assignment.  Can you not shift these all on one line if you're not using the previous version?  You may also find that doing a `std::move()`  would buy you some time if you're using c++11?

Comment: I am using C++11

Comment: The answer to your question is "I don't know".

Comment: When I try to do `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 >>(x) = A-B;`, I get a compilation error: `redefinition of 'x'`

Comment: So it does not seem possible to use the Map class without instantiating an object. This is at the heart of the question...

Comment: I don't see why you would need to instantiate an object, but I simply can't figure out how to perform this action without instantiating a Map object.

Comment: What's the matter with `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 >> constraint(std::move(A-B));`?

Comment: The Map constructor takes the pointer that you want to write to. In this case, that is 'x'.

Comment: `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 >>(x) = A-B;` is equivalent to `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 >> x = A-B;`. If you need the map only once (and don't want to name it), you can write `Eigen::Matrix<T, N,1>::Map(x) = A-B;`. And I suggest to make a typedef for `Matrix<T,N,1>`.

Comment: I did make a typedef for the Matrix in my actual code (since I am using it often). But I didn't know about that cool Map feature. Nice...

Comment: @UKMonkey `std::move` won't help here, since a `Map` can't take ownership of other memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines of code:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, N, 1 >> constraint(x);
constraint = A - B;
```

are essentially compiled by Eigen as:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
  x[i] = A[i] - B[i];
```

The reality is a bit more complicated because of explicit unrolling, and explicit vectorization (both depends on T), but that's essentially it. So the construction of the `Map` object is essentially a no-op (it is optimized away by any compiler) and no, there is no extra copy going on here.

Actually, if your profiler is able to tell you that the bottleneck lies on this simple expression, then that very likely means that this piece of code has not been inlined, meaning that you did not enabled compiler optimizations flags (like `-O3` with gcc/clang).

Comment: Funny you should mention it... I turned off O3 to try to get a better idea of what was going on. I did that because, with O3 on, about 20 lines of code were getting lumped together. So with O3 on, it was basically impossible to profile.